# Storing values of a Fibonacci sequence w/ recursion with minimal runtime

Tags: java, recursion, containers, fibonacci

I know my code has a lot of issues right now, but I just want to get the ideas correct before trying anything. I need to have a method which accepts an integer n that returns the nth number in the Fibonacci sequence. While solving it normally with recursion, I have to minimize runtime so when it gets something like the 45th integer, it will still run fairly quickly. Also, I can't use class constants and globals.

The normal way w/ recursion.

```
public static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) { // to indicate the first two elems in the sequence 
        return 1;
    } else { // goes back to very first integer to calculate (n-1) and (n+1) for (n)
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2); 
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is that there is a lot of redundancy in this process. I figure that I can create a List to calculate up to nth elements so it only run through once before i return the nth element. However, I am having trouble seeing how to use recursion in that case though.

If I am understanding it correctly, the standard recursive method is slow because there are a lot of repeats:

fib(6) = fib(5) + fib(4)

fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3)

fib(4) = fib(3) + 1

fib(3) = 1 + 1

Is this the correct way of approaching this? Is it needed to have some form of container to have a faster output while still being recursive? Should I use a helper method? I just recently got into recursive programming and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this since I've been so used to iterative approaches. Thanks.

Here's my flawed and unfinished code:

```
public static int fasterFib(int n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (n <= 2) { // if 
        return 1;
    } else if (results.size() <= n){ // If the list has fewer elems than 
        results.add(0, 1);
        results.add(0, 1);
        results.add(results.get(results.size() - 1 + results.get(results.size() - 2)));
        return fasterFib(n); // not sure what to do with this yet
    } else if (results.size() == n) { // base case if reached elems
        return results.get(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you HAVE to use recursion?

Comment: Yes. That's the hard part if I want to use containers to store values. Should I ditch the containers idea then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` instead of a `List`. You should probably move that collection outside of your method (so it can cache the results) -

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();

public static int fasterFib(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if (n <= 2) { // if
    return 1;
  }
  if (results.get(n) != null) {
    return results.get(n);
  } else {
    int v = fasterFib(n - 1) + fasterFib(n - 2);
    results.put(n, v);
    return v;
  }
}
```

This optimization is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), from the Wikipedia article -

> In computing, memoization is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by keeping the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

Comment: Great answer, and just to point something else out, the choice of HashMap is due to Hashes being (most of the time) O(1), which is pretty quick, it doesn't need to iterate to find a value !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have said this earlier, but I'm also not allowed to use class constants or globals.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Map::computeIfAbsent method (since 1.8) to re-use the already calculated numbers.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Fibonacci {

    private final Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public int fib(int n) {
        if (n <= 2) {
            return n;
        } else {
            return cache.computeIfAbsent(n, (key) -> fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```
if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if (n <= 2) { 
    return 1;
  }

Answer (score 2):

The other way to do this is to use a helper method.

```
static private int fibonacci(int a, int b, int n) {
  if(n == 0) return a;
  else return fibonacci(b, a+b, n-1);
}

static public int fibonacci(int n) {
  return fibonacci(0, 1, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a class and a private static HashMap?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Fibonacci {
    private static HashMap<Integer,Long> cache = new HashMap<Integer,Long>();

    public Long get(Integer n) {
        if ( n <= 2 ) {
            return 1L;
        } else if (cache.containsKey(n)) {
            return cache.get(n);
        } else {
            Long result = get(n-1) + get(n-2);
            cache.put(n, result);
            System.err.println("Calculate once for " + n);
            return result;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fibonacci f = new Fibonacci();
        System.out.println(f.get(10));
        System.out.println(f.get(15));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Fibonacci {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();


    private void addToCache(int index, int value) {

        cache.put(index, value);


    }

    private int getFromCache(int index) {

        return cache.computeIfAbsent(index, this::fibonacci);

    }


    public int fibonacci(int i) {

        if (i == 1)

            addToCache(i, 0);

        else if (i == 2)
            addToCache(i, 1);
        else
            addToCache(i, getFromCache(i - 1) + getFromCache(i - 2));

        return getFromCache(i);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use memoization (store the values you already have in an array, if the value at a given index of this array is not a specific value you have given to ignore --> return that).

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    int[] memo = new int[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1 ; i++) {
        memo[i] = -1;
    }

    System.out.println(fib(n,memo));


}

static int fib(int n, int[] memo){
    if (n<=1){
        return n;
    }
    if(memo[n] != -1){
        return memo[n];
    }
    memo[n] = fib(n-1,memo) + fib(n-2,memo);
    return memo[n];
}
```

Explaination:

**memo** :

```
 -> int array (all values -1)
 -> length (n+1) // easier for working on index
```

1. You assign a value to a given index of memo ex: memo[2]
2. memo will look like [-1,-1, 1, ..... ]
3. Every time you need to know the fib of 2 it will return memo[2] -> 1

Which saves a lot of computing time on bigger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<Integer, Integer(){
    {
      put(0, 1);
      put(1, 1);
    }
  };
  /**
   * Smallest fibonacci sequence program using dynamic programming.
   * @param n
   * @return
   */
  public static int fibonacci(int n){
    return n < 2 ? n : cache.computeIfAbsent(n, (key) -> fibonacci( n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static long Fib(int n, Dictionary<int, long> dict)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
            return n;
        if (dict.ContainsKey(n))
            return dict[n]; 
       
        var value = Fib(n - 1,dict) + Fib(n - 2,dict);
        dict[n] = value;
        return value;
    }
```