# Java: Fibonacci use HashMap or TreeMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was asked to implement a Fibonacci program that can be reused again. I used a Hashmap below. Just curious, if I should have actually implemented a TreeMap to help performance? I was looking through resources and keep reading that Hashmap is better for performance, Treemap is for iterating and memory saving. What would be the ideal data structure, or does it matter?

```
public class Fibonacci {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>() {{
        map.put(0, 0);
        map.put(1, 1);
    }};

    int currentMax = 1;

    public int getFibonacci(int newIndex) {
        if (newIndex > currentMax) {
            for (int i = currentMax + 1; i <= newIndex; i++) {
                int newData = map.get(i - 1) + map.get(i - 2);
                map.put(i, newData);
            }
            currentMax = newIndex;
        }
        
        return map.get(newIndex);
    }
}
```

Note: I do not know how big the hashmap will be, as program can be used multiple times.

Comment: I would use neither and opt to use an `int[]` as cache instead.

Comment: That is what [`System::arraycopy` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) is for.

Comment: So I would keep copying the whole array, everytime the program was called eg 50 times, where a user keeps increasing max index? I feel like just adding a single entry would be better, can you explain further, if I'm incorrect? thanks @Turing85

Comment: The typical approach is doubling the size of the array, amortized costs is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: interesting? can you write an answer, and I can send points? so we double the size of array everytime max is increased? and yep, array is faster than hashmap,thanks

Comment: hi @Turing85 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816735/storing-values-of-a-fibonacci-sequence-w-recursion-with-minimal-runtime seems like there is already a question, maybe I can close this question, and you can add an answer to that? not sure if they have optimal answer either, whatever works, not sure if its really the same question either

Comment: The question you linked is not an exact duplicate, in particular: the answers do not touch the point of autoboxing, amortized costs and/or the usage of an array-cache instead, and the base-algorithm is recursive, not iterative (the last is a minor point)

Comment: you could use an `ArrayList` if you don't want to use an array instead of a `Map`

Comment: The standard HashMap implementation stores its nodes in an array which will be expanded by copying as needed.  Thus HashMap isn't going to be cheaper than an array implementation, assuming sensible expansion choices are made in your array implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using neither and use an `int[]` instead, doubling the size if needed.

Rationale:

1. Auto(un)boxing costs time.
2. The insertion to the map costs time. It is specified as `O(1)`, but the actual cost is noticeable.
3. The doubling-strategy guarantees amortized cost for inserting `n` elements of `O(n)` (we cannot do better, adding `n` elements will always have a baseline cost of `O(n)`, it is the same as the insert costs of [`ArrayList` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)).

Putting it all together leads to the following linear time algorithm for calculating the `n`-th Fibonacci-number:

```
class Scratch {
  public static final int INITIAL_CACHE_CAPACITY = 8;
  private static int[] cache = new int[INITIAL_CACHE_CAPACITY];
  private static int currentMax = 1;

  static {
    cache[1] = 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("fib(10) = %d%n", fib(10));
    System.out.printf("fib(20) = %d%n", fib(20));
    System.out.printf("fib(30) = %d%n", fib(30));
    System.out.printf("fib(40) = %d%n", fib(40));
  }

  static int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >= 0");
    }
    if (n <= currentMax) {
      return cache[n];
    }
    if (n >= cache.length) {
      resizeCache(n);
    }
    for (int index = currentMax + 1; index <= n; ++index) {
      cache[index] = cache[index - 1] + cache[index - 2];
    }
    if (currentMax < n) {
      currentMax = n;
    }
    return cache[n];
  }

  private static void resizeCache(int minCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = calculateNewCacheCapacity(minCapacity);
    int currentCapacity = cache.length;
    if (newCapacity < currentCapacity) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("newCapacity must be larger than the current capacity");
    }
    int[] newCache = new int[newCapacity];
    System.arraycopy(cache, 0, newCache, 0, currentCapacity);
    cache = newCache;
  }
  
  
  private static int calculateNewCacheCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    int newSize = cache.length;
    while (newSize <= minCapacity) {
      newSize *= 2;
    }
    return newSize;
  }
}
```

[<kbd>`ideone.com` example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4ciLWk)

Comment: thanks, one last question, if I didn't use array int[] with doubling? what would be the second best choice out of the two (HashMap or TreeMap) ?

Comment: I don't know. Why not try it out?